# isql connect to default database

Tags: postgresql, unixodbc, isql

I am using ODBC to connect to my remote postgresql. I am trying to connect to PG.VSAM database using isql. But it is connecting with default postgres database.

I ran below command -

isql PG.VSAM

it connected to the database but when I ran below query -

select current_database();
it gives 'postgres' as output

Any suggestion how can I connect to PG.VSAM in isql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it in the `odbc.ini` file. Check http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/mwm/7-0/Content/topics/databases/odbc (point #4).

and the try using: `isql -v <connection string>`.